# MySQL - max(column)+1 in a varchar only for integers

Tags: mysql, integer, max, varchar

I have a column with integers like 0000000001, 0000000002  and sometimes xxxxxxxxxx in a varchar type lenght 10.
i need to get a max(column)+1 only or 0000000002 so that follow the 0000000003.
but now because a xxxxxxxxxx inside it starts at 0000000001 again.

SELECT max(ID)+1

Comment: Why do you use ‘SELECT MAX(..)  + 1..’ sounds like your implemented your own string based auto_increment?

Comment: Why don't you use a simple autoincrement with zerofill property?

Comment: because its a software which uses the database too.
these make transaction queries with xxxxxxxxx values normal ids are integer incrementel. autoincrement with zerofill property gives sure problems with the xxxxxxxxx inserts from the software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding a number to a string that's not a number, it'll return the number.

'foo' + 42 = 42

And because you select `MAX(ID)` it returns the 'xxxxxxxxxx'.

The simpliest fix for this is to tweak that calculation a little bit.

```
SELECT max(ID+1) from yourtable
```

Because that way, the 1 that gets returned from that 'xxxxxxxxxx'+1 won't be the MAX.

Or select those that are higher than 0.

```
select LPAD(MAX(ID)+1, 10, '0') 
from yourtable
where id > 0
```